# Accessing a dynamic RadioButtonList array object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created an array of RadioButtonList class, but apparently can't seem to access it or use the answer retrieved from it. I always get the exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
  static int jimmy = 0;


    protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int sizeOfPain = GlobalVariables.sympLCWR1Pain.Count;

        RadioButtonList[] RBLPain = new RadioButtonList[sizeOfPain];

        Label1.Visible = false;
        RadioButtonList1.Visible = false;


        Label[] Labella = new Label[sizeOfPain];

        if (jimmy < sizeOfPain)
        {
            Labella[jimmy] = new Label();
            RBLPain[jimmy] = new RadioButtonList();

            Labella[jimmy].Text = GlobalVariables.sympLCWR1Pain[jimmy];

            RBLPain[jimmy].Items.Add("Yes");

            RBLPain[jimmy].Items.Add("No");

            Panel1.Controls.Add(Labella[jimmy]);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(RBLPain[jimmy]);



                if (RBLPain[jimmy].SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    GlobalVariables.sympLCWR1Yes.Add(GlobalVariables.sympLCWR1Pain[jimmy]);
                }


        }

        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "YOUS DONE!";

                Label3.Text = GlobalVariables.sympLCWR1Yes[0];

            Button5.Visible = false;

        }  

        jimmy++;


    }
```

i get the exception at the if condition. Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What that error means is that you are trying to access something that hasn't yet been instantiated.  In your updated code, I see you have the following within your click event handler:

```
 RadioButtonList[] RBLPain = new RadioButtonList[sizeOfPain];
 Label[] Labella = new Label[sizeOfPain];
```

This means that every time the click event is handled, you are redeclaring the `RBLPain` and `Labella` arrays.  Also, when execution leaves leaves the handler, the variables fall out of scope, so you will not be able to use them in other functions, or use the changes made within the handler from one call to the next.  I don't know what the rest of your code is doing, but despite the seemingly unnecessary arrays, execution should survive your click event.

In your original post you were trying to access the `SelectedItem.Text` property of the `RBLPain[jimmy]`.  In this revision you are checking the `SelectedIndex` instead.  When `SelectedIndex` is -1, `SelectedItem` will be null, perhaps this led to your original problem.  Regardless of what is changed on your form, because you are creating a new `RadioButtonList` during every click event, you are not working with the values from your form - `SelectedIndex` will always be -1 from what I can see.

Comment: iam sorry about the 'jimmy'..just edited it. I select "Yes" everytime i run the code, and whenever i press the button which contains the list the nullReferenceException occurs..i also tried to put the code inside an if(RBLPain[0].SelectedItem != null)..still doesnt work..can't understand why though

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the postBack property or something?

Comment: Can you post an expanded code sample with the location of the initialization steps and the event handling code?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you checking the condition .If you are creating rbl on buttonclick first item should always get selected. Anyway use `RBLPain[jimmy].SelectedIndex=0;`before if condition.